# Save multiples Objects At Once Mongo(Many To Many Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

this is my scene:

I have 2 collections(tables):Projects and students(the relation is many to many).

My models are:

- Project:

  ```
  var ProjectSchema = new Schema({

  name: {
      type: String            
  },
  description: {
      type: String                
  },
  user : {
      type : Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref : "User"
  }
       });      
  Mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
  ```
- User:

  ```
  var Userchema = new Schema({

  name: {
      type: String            
  },
  surname: {
      type: String                
  },
  project : {
      type : Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref : "Project"
   }
     });      
  Mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
  ```

In my view I have 2 inputs where receive name and description of project, then have multiselect where choose 1 or multiples users for this project. When I Click OK should:

1. Create project, and add to user all users selected as objects in BBDD.
2. Update user, with project asociation.

I try the next, but only funcion if I choose 1 user:

```
exports.addUserProject = function(req, res) {   

var project=new svmp.Project();

project.name=req.body.name;
project.description=req.body.description;   
project.user=req.body.user[0]._id;  

project.save(function(err,project){
    if (err) {
        return res.send(400, {
            message : getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(project);
    }
  })
 };
```

The result in my BBDD is the next:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a200a38fae140913ac5413"), "user" : ObjectId("578f41ddb0641d961416c3f5"), "name" : "Project1", "Description" : "Project1 Desc","__v" : 0 }

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your schema definition, since the relationship is many-to-many, you should change the `ref` to an array of the referenced objects. For example change the `user` property of `projectSchema` to an array of object ids like so,

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
      name: {
        type: String            
      },
     description: {
       type: String                
      },
    user : [{
      type : Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref : "User"
     }]
   });
```

Do the same for the `project` property of the `userSchema`.

Secondly, on this line `project.user=req.body.user[0]._id`; you are setting the the `_id` of only the first selected user as the user while ignoring every other selected users. This is why your code only works for one user. Instead, I will suggest you use a simple loop to push all selected users' `_id` to the project's `user` property. You can use a `forEach` loop as given below.

```
var selectedUsers = req.body.user;
selectedUsers.forEach(function(u){
  project.user.push(u._id)
})
```

You can also do this with a simple `for loop`  if you wish.

I believe the suggestions above should fix the issues you described.